# How to make repeating value into null after merging 2 different columns with different number of rows in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

[image]

This is the output I have, but from my query, it is suppose to be like this:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Error_Code AS ISEC, COUNT(Error_Code) AS EC1 FROM COMPIS 
WHERE Error_Code <> ' ' AND test_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-02-06 18:00:00' GROUP BY Error_Code) AS x,
(SELECT error_code AS SCEC, COUNT(error_code) AS EC2 FROM COMPSER 
WHERE error_code <> ' ' AND test_date_time BETWEEN '2020-01-01 06:00:00' AND '2020-02-06 18:00:00' GROUP BY error_code) AS y
ORDER BY EC1 DESC
```

Is there any way to make those duplicated value into null or blanks?
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: That sounds like the sort of thing you should do in your application...

Comment: 100% agree with @Nick … but you got me intrigued by the challenge

Answer (score 0):

A couple statements first...

First, formatting is definitely something that should be done by your application, reporting platform, BI tool, etc. The answer below should be viewed in terms of a "code golf" scenario.  You asked how to do something, and I became interested in the challenge despite my opinion of whether it was a good idea or not.

Second, you list both sql-server and mysql tags.  My given answer will only work on sql-server.

With those two disclaimers out of the way.  [Lead and Lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) allow you to access the values of preceding and following rows.  They add an extremely useful utility for BI calculations that depend on the values of other rows.

From a purely "code golf" scenario you could accomplish what you ask using them to display an empty string instead of the actual value when it's a duplicate of the previous value.  Order of rows obviously matters which is why the over clause is a critical part of lead and lag statements.  This specific sample is of limited use, uses sample data from your question, but accomplishes what you asked.

```
create table test_table (
  isec varchar(50), 
  ec1 varchar(50), 
  scec varchar(50), 
  ec2 varchar(50)
);

insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0038 E0037','74','E0039','10');
insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0001','45','E0039','10');
insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0004 E0005','31','E0039','10');
insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0024','16','E0039','10');
insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0018','6','E0039','10');
insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0024','16','E0040','12');
insert into test_table (isec,ec1,scec,ec2) values ('E0018','6','E0040','12');

select isec, 
       ec1, 
       case when scec = lag(scec) OVER (ORDER BY scec, ec2) then '' else scec end as scec, 
       case when ec2 = lag(ec2) OVER (ORDER BY scec, ec2) then '' else ec2 end as ec2
from test_table;
```

You can see it in action with this sql fiddle link:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cb88/5/7